SearchKit seems to be conflating two Activity Types
Odd behavior I've noticed:
I have an Activity Type with ID 78 and Label [just an example] "Activity Type X"
I have another Activity Type with ID 79 and Label "Activity Type Y"
Using the API or the standard builtin Activity search, I can query these activities as you would expect.
Using SearchKit though, when I select either of these two, it will only search for ID 78. When I look at the Query info Tab, the SQL always looks like:
    SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`subject` AS `subject`, `a`.`activity_type_id` AS `activity_type_id:label`
FROM civicrm_activity a
WHERE (`a`.`activity_type_id` = "78")
  AND (`a`.`is_test` = "0")
  AND (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
ORDER BY `a`.`subject` ASC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0

And the API section looks like:
{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "id",
    "subject",
    "activity_type_id:label"
  ],
  "orderBy": {},
  "where": [
    [
      "activity_type_id:name",
      "=",
      "Activity Type Y"
    ]
  ],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [],
  "having": []
}

That is, the label from one type and the ID from the other!
Any thoughts?

Probably the name is different from the label. The most common cause
for that is that you created the activity and then renamed it, which would have altered the label but not the name.
You should inspect your civicrm_option_value table and compare activity names with labels.

That looks to be exactly correct, thanks. Can I just change the name in the DB or is that going to cause problems somewhere else?

As long as you don't have any other saved searches (or custom code) referring to that activity type, it should be safe to change the name.
